# Stack output in C

Tags: c, gdb, stack

in advance: I do not want any 'ready-to-use' solution. Especially, imho it would defeat the purpose to learn something. And this is my primary goal: what I'd like to have is a few explainations/hints, or deeper understanding.

Now to the problem:

After using gdb and setting a breakpoint the following output of the stack is generated ( c-program):

The question that emerges now is:

```
0xbfa62f84:0x08048350 0xbfa62fe8 0xb7df0390 0x00000001

0xbfa62f94:0xbfa63014 0xbfa6301c 0xb7f262d0 0x00000000
```

for what do the values stand for? Or how can they be disassembled/decomposed?
I assume that they encode the memory address + some OP-code like mov, sub etc. 
But how? and why? Or asked in a different fashion: how can these instructions be 'read out'?

Thanks in advance

Dan

Comment: The stack is for data, not for code. You won't see any "instructions" on the stack.

Comment: the stack will contain anti-stacksmashing sentinels (if any), return address of the calling code, caller state information, local vars created in the function, etc... None of that is "code".

Comment: if somebody can understand a bunch of hexcode without any context, he must be a genius.

Comment: ok, check `0x08048350`. you want to disassemble code there, not in the stack.

Comment: We don't know your code. We also don't know where you put your breakpoint, except for an address. Finally, the output you shown is not something that a simple breakpoint hit would print. Please, someone correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: If you want to understand the stack, you need to understand the ABI (calling convention) for your target.  Then you should read the disassembly of your program to see where it is putting each local variable on the stack relative to the stack frame for each function.

Comment: What IDE are you using? That's a rhetorical question. Point is that if you aren't using an IDE, you should be.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand the such a flow use a debugger like Keil .There at the same time you can see the assembly code and the generated hex file and your source code at the same time .Then when you step through the code you will understand how the assembly is related to the hex file and source code.

Answer (score 1):

Machine code is not stored in the stack; however, the return address stored in the stack frame points to machine code.  `0x08048350` is a good candidate for a code address (on x86, the code segment starts at a low address); you can examine the memory starting at that address and try to puzzle out opcodes and registers.

Or you could use the gdb command `x/i` to display the instructions starting at that address - `x/16i 0x08048350` will display the first 16 instructions starting at that address.